# pmdarima auto_arima crashes with single value change

Tags: time-series, python, forecasting

I'm working on a time series forescast model with `pmdarima`.

My time series is short, but not so bad behaved. The following code gives an error on sklearn\utils\validation.py

```py
from pmdarima import auto_arima
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
import datetime
import pandas as pd

datelist = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=24, freq='MS')

sales = [26.000000,27.100000,26.000000,28.014286,28.057143,
         30.128571,39.800000,33.000000,37.971429,45.914286,
         37.942857,33.885714,36.285714,34.971429,40.042857,
         27.157143,30.685714,35.585714,43.400000,51.357143,
         45.628571,49.942857,42.028571,52.714286]


df = pd.DataFrame(data=sales,index=datelist,columns=['sales'])

observations = df['sales']
size = df['sales'].size
shape = df['sales'].shape
maxdate = max(df.index).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
mindate = min(df.index).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")


asc = seasonal_decompose(df, model='add')

if asc.seasonal[asc.seasonal.notnull()].size == df['sales'].size:
    seasonality = True
else:
    seasonality = False

# Check Stationarity
aftest = adfuller(df['sales'])

if aftest[1] <= 0.05:
    stationarity = True
else:
    stationarity = False

results = auto_arima(observations,
                     seasonal=seasonality,
                     stationary=stationarity,
                     m=12,
                     error_action="ignore")
```

```
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    584                              " minimum of %d is required%s."
    585                              % (n_samples, array.shape, ensure_min_samples,
--> 586                                 context))
    587 
    588     if ensure_min_features > 0 and array.ndim == 2:

ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0,)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

However, if I change the first value of the sales series from 26 to 30 it works.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

not a problem here perhaps your software can't detect seasonal dummies or the need to take a log xform. As to the cause of the first value alteration , I can only suggest software malfunction.

[image]